# Python - Browser wont finish request when custom headers are sent

Tags: python, http-headers

I'm currently making a live radio service that will rely on custom headers. But when I send them the browser never loads the audio content page.
Here is what im sending:

```
 # self.header is an `OrderedDict`
 # the header `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` is sent in the `HEADER` function

 self.header['Content-Type'] = 'audio/mpeg'
 self.header['XYZ-mount-point'] = config.MOUNT_POINT
 self.header['XYZ-artist'] = mp3.MP3(self.files[self.count]).artist()
 self.header['XYZ-album'] = mp3.MP3(self.files[self.count]).album()
 self.header['XYZ-title'] = mp3.MP3(self.files[self.count]).title()
 self.header['XYZ-duration'] = mp3.MP3(self.files[self.count]).duration()
 self.header['Connection'] = 'keep-alive'
 self.header['Content'] = buffer # raw audio data to be played
 header.HEADER(self.header, con) # sends the headers
```

if I remove the XYZ headers everything works perfectly, is sending custom headers not possible?

Just in case:

```
def HEADER(HEADER, csock):
    string = ""
    csock.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n")
    for k, v in HEADER.items():
            if not k == "Content":
                    string += '%s:%s\n' % (k, v)
            elif k == "Content":
                    string+="\n\n"+v
                    csock.send(string)
```